# nested for loop in node js with asynchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have `userCurrentContainer = [[],[{"1":"xyz"},{"2":"abc"}],[{"1":"xyz"}],[]]`

I to want to group by key so the output will look like: `{ 1: xyzxyz, 2: abc}`

I am using async Library.
I understood grouping logic .. 
but my problem is when everything done then i will callback.. 
but it is before calling..

```
function grupbyContainerId(userCurrentContainer,callback){
            var track=0;
            var temp=new Array();
            async.eachSeries(userCurrentContainer, function (key,callback1) {
                track=track+1

                if(key.length>0){
                    var innertrack=0;
                    async.eachSeries(key, function (key1,callback2) {
                         innertrack=innertrack+1
                         //logic here 

                         if(track>=userCurrentContainer.length&&innertrack,key.length>=key.length){
                            console.log("if calledd ---------->");
                            callback(null,temp)
                         }

                        callback2();
                    })
                }

                callback1();

            });

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, reffer to http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries
It should have 3 params. Try something like that:

```
function doSomeAction() {
var someNestedArray = [[],[{key:'value1'}],[],[{key:'value2'}]];
async.eachSeries(someNestedArray, function (item, next) {
    async.eachSeries(item, function (deepObj, cb) {
        console.log(deepObj)
        cb()
    }, function (err, result) {
        next();
    })

}, function (err, res) {
    console.log('AllWorkDone');
})}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the basic input/output example you give, I think using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) might be a better fit for you. E.g.

```
const input = [[],[{"1":"xyz"},{"2":"abc"}],[{"1":"xyz"}],[]];
const output = input.reduce(function (acc, value) {
  for (let val of value) {
    acc[Object.keys(val)] = val[Object.keys(val)] + (acc[Object.keys(val)] || '');
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```